# SQL - Finding minimum value among table fields and joined fields

Tags: sql

Here's an interesting and perhaps good general problem. How would I find the minimum time value corresponding to an ID in a particular table. Hard to explain without an example, so here is one:

- Table A has fields ID, stage1_date, stage2_date
- Table B1 has fields A_ID (fk to A.ID), date
- Table B2 has fields A_ID (fk to A.ID), date

I want to find the minimum value among A.stage1_date, A.stage2_date, B1.date, B2.date for each ID in A.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What platform is this on?

Comment: this would actually be on vertica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `least()` function returns `NULL` if any of its arguments are `NULL`.  And, you probably want to use left outer joins for this purpose, in case one of the B tables is missing an `A_ID`.

Here is a safer method:

```
select id, min(thedate) as mindate
from (select id, stage1_date as thedate from a union all
      select id, stage2_date from a union all
      select a_id, date from b1 union all
      select a_id, date from b2
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: ok this looks very promising, i will have to test and let you know how it fares

Comment: also i have tried the nested queries with unions to solve, but this def looks to work out some things that i couldnt fig out

Comment: @SS781 . . . What is the issue?  This query seems pretty easy to follow.

Comment: u sir are a genius http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25cdf5/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEAST()` function to return the smallest value in a list of expressions:

```
SELECT 
    LEAST(A.stage1_date, A.stage2_date, B1.date, B2.date) 
FROM 
    A JOIN B1 ON A.ID = B1.A_ID 
      JOIN B2 ON A.ID = B2.A_ID
```

Comment: you have a typo, also isn't LEAST only on Oracle?

Comment: ok, so i honestly had no idea there is a least function, that is super useful...i was trying to tackle this with two nested subqueries with multiple unions

Comment: i believe LEAST works for vertica: https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#11792.htm

Comment: This assumes that both b tables have exactly one row for each and every `A_ID`.

Comment: they would not in my case...